# Deny activity access on user login

Tags: android

I would like to deny access to an activity, say the user profile edit activity, if the user has not yet logged in with a REST request to the server.

For now, after the user has successfully logged in he is stored locally on the phone preferences.

```
protected void onPostExecute(ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity) {
    HttpHeaders headers = responseEntity.getHeaders();
    if (null != headers) {
        List<String> values = headers.get(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER_AUTH_TOKEN);
        if (null != values && values.size() > 0) {
            String token = values.get(0);
            if (null != token) {
                loginActivity.storeUser(responseEntity.getBody(), token);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void storeUser(User user, String token) {
    if (null != user) {
        SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER_EMAIL, user.getEmail());
        editor.putString(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER_JWT, token);
        editor.apply();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I wonder how to deny access to the profile edit activity.

Here is how I retrieve the stored email address from the preferences:

```
private boolean getProfile() {
    SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    String email = settings.getString(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER_EMAIL, null);
    String token = settings.getString(Constants.LOGGED_IN_USER_JWT, null);
    new UserProfileAsyncTask(this, email, token).execute();
    return false;
}
```

Any hints on strategy to adopt are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onCreate() method of your Profile Edit activity, check to see if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in then simply redirect them back to the Login activity using an Intent.

Comment: That means I have to add this check in every activity that requires the user to be logged in. Any strategy on how to implement this once for multiple activities ?

Comment: I don't think there's any other way to do this. This is how we do things in web applications too. Besides, it's just a simple if-else check.